# Alternative solutions to a server database

Tags: javascript, jquery, database

I am looking for a temporary database solution that i could use on a shared folder. I have a simple CRUD style website created with bootstrap and jquery. I would need a light database to enter about 600 entries a year

Ive looked at using MS access 2010 to create a local database in my shared folder and then try to use javascript to connect to it. Problem is there is very little information online and this but dosent seem to work with chrome as you seem to need activex. Looked at Couchdb but you seem to need to comunicate via http so it wont work since i dont have a web server.

Curios to hear if anyone would know of other solutions?

Comment: Why not a local web server?   You can easily install a LAMP/WAMP package locally and get http, a database and a language easily for free.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have a web server at the moment but thats exactly what im planning on doing but i need an alternative solution meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically with a front-end only application, you could choose to use LocalStorage (html5), but I'd recommend against it, because if your computer gets wiped for some reason you'll lose your data.

In the end that's the same with a server, but I guess it's still better to get a simple hosting somewhere for +-20 (euro/usd) per year and simply have a mysql database and php backend there to catch your data and store it. You could choose also for nodejs instead of php, although personally I'd use php with a webserver like apache (all included in the year price) and have a stable solution with your hosting provider worrying about backups and all that shit. I think the little extra effort is greatly worth your time in the long run, even if it's only for 600 entries per year.

Comment: Pretty much this, also 600 entries per year is enough to warrant a real database. Most web hosts offer at least a mysql database which you can query with PHP.

Comment: LocalStorage is not shared, or is it ?

Comment: i had the same question would the localstorage be accesible to others? This site would be used by 4-5 of my team members.

Comment: Localstorage is local to the client machine so it is not shared so if there are multiple users this is not an option

Answer (score 0):

> Looked at Couchdb but you seem to need to comunicate via http so it
>   wont work since i dont have a web server.

It doesn't need a web server, CouchDB has an integrated REST API. For light usage, there's free hosting available, for instance [IBM Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/product/pricing/).

Another similar option is [Parse Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) + MongoDB, hosted or local.

So you have the choice of local or hosted DB, depending on your preferences.

And no, you can't directly use network files for DB use from the browser without some kind of plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately due to IT policies i cannot branch out to hosting solutions, its a big nono there. Hoping to be able to get my own web server eventually. About CloudDB, can i use it in a shared folder? I tought i rwad somewhere that you need http for this to work and on my shared drive i can only use file://

Comment: "About CloudDB" It's CouchDB, not CloudDB. It's a REST API, so it's HTTP like a web server, but dedicated to DB usage (think Apache + MySQL wrapped into one, but JSON-based instead of SQL).

Comment: Typo sorry about that, in that case CouchDB is a no go for me then since i cannot communicate via http. I would assume Parse Server is the same idea?

Comment: Yes, same idea, but see the end of my answer for `file://`